# Conditional Navigation Bars?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Depending on the current path (starts with '/members' or not) I need different navigation bars. I was not able to solve it with useLocation() or anything else. Please let me know if you have any idea!

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Router>
          <NavigationBar /> {/* OR MembersNavigationBar */}
          <Layout>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
              <Route exact path="/members/home" component={MembersHome} />
            </Switch>
          </Layout>
        </Router>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It would be great if anybody could recommend a solution...thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by reading the docs and understand better React-Router. Here is the simple solution:

```
...
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/intern" component={MembersNavigationBar} />
        <Route path="/" component={NavigationBar} />
      </Switch>
...
```